# How can I recognise gestures in an Apple Watch app?

Tags: ios, gesture-recognition, watchkit, apple-watch

Is it possible to do gesture recognition on the Apple watch?

For instance, Apple have demonstrated using swipe gestures on the Watch, left, right, up, and down. Is it possible to capture these in a third party Watch app, and link them to methods in my WatchKit extension?

Also, is it possible to do custom gesture recognitions, such as a circle or triangle gesture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not currently possible on Apple Watch. 
Use menu instead.

Comment: I know that you can connect more WKInterfaceController in Stroyboard and that change them with swipe left/right. Co I was thinking that same thing is possible programatically.

Comment: yes but the watch screen will be so small. Imagine you trying to draw a triangle with your finger. Got to be difficult.

Comment: Point was that for changing WKInterfaceController swipe is enable, but if I want to use swipe programmatically that is not possible.

Comment: i'm not sure to understand. You have a paged based app and you want to present one particular interface ?

Comment: If you have 2 WKInterfaceController and connect them in Storyboard, with swipe you can go from one to another. If I want to have one WKInterfaceController and one label with number on it, on swipe right increase number by one and on swipe left decrease number by one I do not see how to do it. So Swipe is enabled, but you can not use it programatically. Do you understand now ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no access to swipes or other gestures or tap locations in WatchKit at present, and there is no reason to believe that is going to change before the release of the Watch.

Apple supports the use of swipe gestures to navigate forward and back through your controllers, and to scroll the views it has laid out. These are handled by the Watch OS—you only have the ability to define the segues and layout of the objects in Interface Builder and the OS takes care of the rest. There are however no equivalents to UIGestureRecognisers, so you can't use swipe gestures as gesture-based controls for other app elements at present. It is unclear whether Apple may be willing to enable this in the future, or whether they will never open this up to developers, but they are encouraging developers to submit enhancement requests via their [bug reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com).